# Does TypeScript (or some library) have a way to go from func((x) => x.y()) to `func(_.y())?

Tags: typescript

A simple example with map:

```
const strings = ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant'];
const stringLengths = strings.map((s) => s.length)
```

What I'd love to be able to write is:

```
const strings = ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant'];
const stringLengths = strings.map(_.length)
```

(Scala supports a construct like this.)

I'm wondering if anyone has implemented something like this? I tried an approach with the Proxy class and I could probably get it to work, but I couldn't get it to be anything near type safe.

Comment: The only thing you can do here is to create a variable `const len = (s) => s.length` and use `strings.map(len)` otherwise there is no different syntax for it in JS/TS currently

Comment: You could define a function `const pluck = <T extends any[]>(t: T, key: keyof T[number]) => t.map((v) => v[key]);` and call that as `const stringLengths = pluck(strings, 'length');`. If you wanted to, you could even pollute the `Array` prototype with something like that, allowing you to just do `strings.pluck('length')`.

Comment: ah, I see. I mean theoretically you can transform anything of form `s.whatever` to `((s)=>s.whatever)(s)`, so being able to do such a transform would allow you to then pass in the modified function, but it sounds like short of macros or something, it's not possible to do it fully generically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Lodash allows directly specifying properties as convenience `_.map(strings, "length")`

```js
const strings = ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant'];
const result = _.map(strings, "length");
console.log( result );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The string is a shorthand for [`_.property()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#property) which can also be used stand-alone in a regular `.map()` call:

```js
const strings = ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant'];
const result = strings.map(_.property("length"));
console.log( result );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

For calling methods instead of just extracting properties use [`_method()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#method):

```js
const strings = ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant'];

//without arguments
const shout = _.method("toUpperCase");
//with arguments
const shorten = _.method("slice", 1, 7);

console.log( strings.map(shout) );
console.log( strings.map(shorten) );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

See also [Lodash FP](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) which is a more functional programming-friendly version of Lodash where all functions are auto curried and put data last to more easily enable composition and reuse:

```js
const extractLength = _.map("length");
const strings = ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant'];
console.log( extractLength(strings) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-fp/0.10.4/lodash-fp.min.js"></script>
```

---

To use Lodash with TypeScript, install [the typings from the DefinitelyTyped project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash):

```bash
npm install --save-dev @types/lodash
```

### [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/)

Ramda fills the same niche as Lodash in that in provides common utilities. It is geared more towards functional programming with all utilities being curried already and supporting function structures like Functors.

Ramda has several ways to process these.

Using [`R.prop()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#prop)

```js
const strings = ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant'];
const result = strings.map(R.prop("length"));
console.log( result );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.29.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Using a lens - lenses are composable getters and setters. In this simple example `R.prop()` is more convenient but for more complex structures and rules for what to view, a lens might be more appropriate. The usage is as follows:

```js
const strings = ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant'];
const result = strings.map(R.view(R.lensProp("length")));
console.log( result );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.29.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

For calling methods, Ramda offers a [`R.invoker()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#invoker) which is directly comparable to Lodash's `_.method()`:

```js
const strings = ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant'];

//without arguments
const shout = R.invoker(0, "toUpperCase");
//with arguments
const shorten = R.invoker(2, "slice")(1, 7);

console.log( strings.map(shout) );
console.log( strings.map(shorten) );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.29.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

---

Similar to Lodash, to use Ramda in TypeScript, install [the typings from the DefinitelyTyped project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ramda)

```bash
npm install --save-dev @types/ramda
```